# Получение картинки из madelineproto

Tags: php, photo, madelineproto

Никак не могу понять, как именно конвертировать ответ, получаемый из функции get_full_info().

При вызове этой функции возвращается большой массив с данными, всё что касается нужного мне изображение хранится в этом массиве:

```
 [chat_photo] => Array
            (
                [_] => photo
                [has_stickers] => 
                [id] => 336276157113***136
                [access_hash] => -29286***68068216628
                [file_reference] => danog\MadelineProto\TL\Types\Bytes Object
                    (
                        [bytes:danog\MadelineProto\TL\Types\Bytes:private] => ]"u$"���***<��R��c
                    )

                [date] => 152***0821
                [sizes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [_] => photoSize
                                [type] => a
                                [location] => Array
                                    (
                                        [_] => fileLocationToBeDeprecated
                                        [volume_id] => 239***161
                                        [local_id] => 8**50
                                    )

                                [w] => 160
                                [h] => 160
                                [size] => 6644
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [_] => photoSize
                                [type] => b
                                [location] => Array
                                    (
                                        [_] => fileLocationToBeDeprecated
                                        [volume_id] => 239***161
                                        [local_id] => 8**51
                                    )

                                [w] => 320
                                [h] => 320
                                [size] => 13687
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [_] => photoSize
                                [type] => c
                                [location] => Array
                                    (
                                        [_] => fileLocationToBeDeprecated
                                        [volume_id] => 239***161
                                        [local_id] => 8**52
                                    )

                                [w] => 640
                                [h] => 640
                                [size] => 27903
                            )

                    )

                [dc_id] => 2
            )
```

Как это превратить в картинку, или ссылку на картинку - ума не приложу:с

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо из ответа метода [get_full_info](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/get_full_info.html) вытащить по индексу массивов мета информацию о изображении и передать ее полностью на метод [download_to_file](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/docs/FILES.html#extracting-download-info)

Пример:

`$fullInfo = $madelineProto->get_full_info($channelId);
$imageMeta = $fullInfo['full']['chat_photo'];
$madelineProto->download_to_file($imageMeta, '/path/to/save/image.jpg');`

Решение брал [здесь](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto/issues/85#issuecomment-293624094)